# Query for non openers from several emails timing out

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, performance, sql

I can write some SQL, but I'm not good at knowing how to make things perform better. My query below works with one JobID, but I need to pull openers from 5 jobs. When I do this it times out. I'm thinking there is a better way to write this, but I'm still new to SQL and don't know much about what performs better than what. Any suggestions?

```
select distinct s.SubscriberKey
from _sent s
WHERE s.JobID IN ('2787871','2787957','2787958','2787970','2787971')
AND s.SubscriberKey NOT IN (

    SELECT o.SubscriberKey 
    FROM _Open o  
    WHERE s.JobID IN ('2787871','2787957','2787958','2787970','2787971')


)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd write it like this:

```
select distinct s.SubscriberKey
from _sent s
left join _open o on (
       o.jobid = s.jobid 
       and o.subscriber_id = s.subscriberid 
       and o.isunique = 1
)
WHERE s.JobID IN (2787871,2787957,2787958,2787970,2787971)
and o.subscriber_id is null
```

The `jobid` is an number, so treating it like one removes a datatype conversion.  Also you can minimize the criteria to just the essentials in relating the views together -- `jobid` and `subscriberid`.

**Update**

Sometimes starting with Job will mitigate a timeout:

```
select distinct s.SubscriberKey
from _job j
inner join _sent s on (s.jobid = j.jobid)
WHERE j.JobID IN (2787871,2787957,2787958,2787970,2787971)
and not exists (
  select * 
  from _open 
  where o.jobid = s.jobid 
  and o.subscriber_id = s.subscriberid 
  and o.isunique = 1
)
```

Comment: ok but why did you change SubscriberKey to subscriber_id? for clarity sake?

Comment: also I'm getting a validation error, looks like something is out of order here?

Comment: oops. should be fixed now.

Comment: subscriberid is an internal number and not a string, so it's inherently more performant.

Comment: oh ok, but doesn't the _open table have subscriberid too? why did you put subscriber_id?

Comment: That still timed out. there may just be too many job ids. I may have to break this up into smaller queries.